# Excel Macro - Repeat Macro Code But Applied to Different Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and would like to seek some advice.

I'm running a macro to compile tables into a row-by-row transaction list.

However, I do not want to replicate this code 11 times for the different month columns.

How can I perform a loop so it automatically performs the task across all 12 months?

Code below and table conversion as per attached picture.

Thanks!

```
'For Apr'20 - 'Copy name and category to clipboard
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:C15").Copy
    
'Select last row of reference cell

    lastRow = Sheets("Consolidated Cost Sheet_Working").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & lastRow).Select

'Paste clipboard as values

    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
'Copy period and drag down

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Consolidated Cost Sheet_Working").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("D" & lastRow).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Sheets("Consolidated Cost Sheet_Working").Range("C3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FillDown
    
'Copy Financial Info to Sheet

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3:D15").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Consolidated Cost Sheet_Working").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("E" & lastRow).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

**Conversion Table Concept**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you recorded a macro and now you want to generalize the functionality. That's how a lot of us start. Your recorded macro looks like this

```
Sub Macro1()

    ' Lots of code

End Sub
```

The fastest way you can achieve your objective is to alter the original macro to pass the column in as an argument.

```
Sub Macro1(Byval col as String)

    ' Lots of code

End Sub
```

Then replace every instance of column "D" in the macro with column col. For example:

```
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(col & "2").Copy
    lastRow = Sheets("Consolidated Cost Sheet_Working").Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range(col & lastRow).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Then you can call the macro repeatedly from another sub, passing in a different column each time.

```
Sub OtherSub()

    Macro1 "D"
    Macro1 "E"
    Macro1 "F"
    Macro1 "G"

End Sub
```

There are any number of ways this code can be improved (I particularly recommend you read [Some examples of how to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/3817068)), but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! Yes, i recorded some, googled some, and its a whole lot of patchwork. I'll give your solution a go and really appreciate your advice :)

Comment: Hi Nicholas, what code can I use for the following line, in order to loop it to different Columns i.e. "E", "F" etc:

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3:D15").Copy